# Prediction Interval Level on forecast autoplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, forecasting

I have used the forecast package before, and I recall that when using forecast/autoplot that a legend would appear showing the colors for the 80/95% PI, like this picture

[image: old version with PI levels]

However, when running it with version 8.9, running this same code yields the same plot, but without the PI levels legend

```
fdeaths %>% 
 forecast() %>% 
 autoplot()
```

[image: new version without pi levels]

Did the option for displaying this legend go away in later versions of the forecast package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality was moved to fable. Unfortunately this involved removing it from the forecast package due to how ggplot2 searches for scales.

I've just pushed a change to the development version of forecast ([fb57bf](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/commit/fb57bfc0870b728843b3e5c97896aea2c78a8a65)), which will allow the legend to be displayed when the fable/fabletools package is loaded.

The forecast package is now retired for forecasting in R. While we will continue to maintain it via bug fixes, we encourage you to try out the fable package which we are actively developing.

```r
library(fabletools)
library(forecast)
fdeaths %>% 
  forecast() %>% 
  autoplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: On this update, is there an option to color match either the guide to the plot (or vice versa)? It seems that at current they do not match. Will definitely check out fable though. Thanks for the update on this and all of the hard work on these packages!

Comment: The legend colours should be considered the shade of the forecast colour.
For example: if you were plotting multiple forecasts that have different colours, the grayscale 'level' guide indicates the darker or lighter colours.
I am considering showing a different colour in the guide if there is only one forecast colour plotted, but there are no plans for implementing this yet (https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/issues/121)

Changing the `fcol` to be black may more closely match the legend colours.